# Cannot Edit WordPress Themes - Various Errors

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, fastcgi

Our WordPress 2.8.6 installation is returning multiple different errors when trying to edit theme files via wp-admin. The errors are as follows:

"Invalid index."

"The data area passed to a system call is too small"

"The parameter is incorrect."

We've tried deactivating all plugins to no avail. We also tried creating a blank "plugins" directory and also still experienced these errors. Some theme files we are able to edit (very few), but most give one of the three errors above. We also tried switching back to the WordPress Default theme with the same results.

This installation is running on a Windows 2003 Server, IIS 6, PHP 5.3.0, FastCGI 6.1.36.1, and MySQL 5.1.40-community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sounds like your IIS config is messed up.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249721)

Try posting on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/iis) too, this is more of a server config problem than a programming problem I think.

Comment: Thanks, Barnabas! The link you included is only for IIS 4. I doubt that it's also a problem with IIS 6. I wasn't aware of ServerFault.com. I've gone ahead and posted the message there as well. Thanks, again!